# How to access a private nested class in C++?

Tags: c++, inner-classes, private-members

I found a question in CPP quiz. The question is

```
class secret
{
    class hidden{};
public:
    template <class K>
    string accept(K k) {return (k(*this, hidden()));}
    string keyToNextLvl (hidden )const {return ("success!");    }
};

struct SampleSoln
{
    template <class pwd>
    string operator()(const secret &sc, pwd opwd) const
    { return   (sc.keyToNextLvl(opwd)); }
};
int main() 
{
    secret sc;
    cout <<sc.accept(SampleSoln()) << endl; //Prints success
    cout <<sc.keyToNextLvl (AnswerKey()) << endl; //Need to provide the implementation of AnswerKey
}
```

Now I have to access it using a the method "keyToNextLvl" directly. (I am not allowed to access the accept method -sample solution is provided in the ques itself for accessing keyToNextLvl using accept method. So I need to provide the implementation of AnswerKey)

I did a some search and got some ways to access a private members/methods without using friend
http://bloglitb.blogspot.in/2010/07/access-to-private-members-thats-easy.html

But I didn’t get any idea for the solution of above ques.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Got it!

```
struct AnswerKey
{
  template <class T>
  operator T ()
  {
    return T();
  }
};
```

uses a templated conversion operator to construct a `secret::hidden` object

Comment: So how do you call `keyToNextLvl` with it?

Comment: exactly as it is in the question

Comment: Oh, now I get it. At first I thought you overloaded `operator ()`, but now I can see it's the conversion operator (small difference between `T operator ()` and `operator T ()`, he-he). Neat!

Answer (score 3):

For it is default constructible, you can do this:

```
sc.keyToNextLvl ({})
```

As an example:

```
#include<string>
#include<iostream>

class secret
{
    class hidden{};
public:
    template <class K>
    std::string accept(K k) {return (k(*this, hidden()));}
    std::string keyToNextLvl (hidden )const {return ("success!");    }
};

int main() 
{
    secret sc;
    std::cout <<sc.keyToNextLvl ({}) << std::endl;
}
```

You don't need to define `AnswerKey`.
What is not visible is the *name* of the class, but you can construct it as long as you don't require to actually use its name.